# What insights you get by running execute-block for a try-runtime test?

Tags: substrate

Substrate's try-runtime is documented [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/tools/try-runtime/) and [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/frame/try-runtime/cli/src/lib.rs). Though the documents explain how you can try executing a block to test how a particular runtime code performs that execution, they don't explain what kind of reports you would have and what insights you can get out of this test. To explain my question, let's compare this command with the other command on-runtime-upgrade. If you try on-runtime-upgrade, you can see which pallets would need/have migration if an upgrade to your under development runtime happens to a chain at a particular state. You can also add pre-upgrade and post-upgrade hooks to a pallet where a migration would happen and then if you try on-runtime-upgrade it will execute those hooks in the expected order and let you examine the sanity of the storage through this process. If the pre-upgrade or post-upgrade hooks return error, then the try-runtime test fails and that is what you expect from a test to show failures before doing the actual runtime upgrade.
Back to the question, is the result of exec-block simply a pass/failed value? What would prompt you to do this test, in the first place?